# Store, manipulate and retrieve content of docx files, retaining formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

So I need a way to retrieve the content of docx files (text, images, foarmatting), store them and then generate a new docx with the content of some of the files stitched together.

My current approach is, that I extract the `<body>` from the underlying `document.xml`, store that in a `Pandas DF` and modify the content of a template docx with data form that DF, before generating a new docx.

Storing the body of the files in a Pandas DF seems easy enough:

```
    def get_word_xml(docx_filename):
       with open(docx_filename, 'rb') as f:
          zip = zipfile.ZipFile(f)
          xml_content = zip.read('word/document.xml')
       return zip, tmp_dir, xml_content
    
    def get_xml_tree(xml_string):
       return etree.fromstring(xml_string)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Text'])
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./docs", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        zip, tmp_dir, wordxml = get_word_xml(os.path.join(root, name).replace("\\","/"))
        wordxml = get_xml_tree(wordxml)
        wordxml = etree.tostring(wordxml, pretty_print=True)
        body = re.search("(?<=<w:body>)(.*)(?=<\/w:body>)",str(wordxml)).group(1)
        df = df.append({'Name':name.split('.')[0], 'Text':body}, ignore_index=True)
```

The actual problem I'm facing is, however, that generating a docx file leads to a corrupted file. I tried opening a file, extracting the contents(not even manipulating the data at this point) and generate a new file with the same content(basically a copy):

```
with open('Test.docx', 'rb') as f:
      zip = zipfile.ZipFile(f)
      xml_content = zip.read('word/document.xml')
      tmp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
      zip.extractall(tmp_dir)

etree.fromstring(xml_content)

with open(os.path.join(tmp_dir,'word/document.xml'), 'w') as f:
    xmlstr = str(xml_content)
    f.write(str(xmlstr))

    filenames = zip.namelist()
    zip_copy_filename = 'output.docx'
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_copy_filename, "w") as docx:
        for filename in filenames:
            docx.write(os.path.join(tmp_dir,filename), filename)

    
shutil.rmtree(tmp_dir)
```

I'm not even sure if this is the right approach for this task, but I used [this](https://virantha.com/2013/08/16/reading-and-writing-microsoft-word-docx-files-with-python/) as reference.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

```
etree.fromstring(xml_content)
```

This doesn't assign the XML `Element` created from `xml_content` to anything.

```
xmlstr = str(xml_content)
f.write(str(xmlstr))
```

First, you have an extra `str` conversion. Second, the correct way to convert the XML back to string is via the [etree tostring() method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element).

Try the following code - on my (linux) system, the generated `output.docx` opens in LibreOffice Writer without problem. (BTW, next time please include complete code, including imports.)

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import zipfile
import tempfile
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import os.path
import shutil

with open('Test.docx', 'rb') as f:
      zip = zipfile.ZipFile(f)
      xml_content = zip.read('word/document.xml')
      tmp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
      zip.extractall(tmp_dir)

xml = etree.fromstring(xml_content)
with open(os.path.join(tmp_dir,'word/document.xml'), 'w') as f:
    xmlstr = etree.tostring(xml, encoding="unicode", xml_declaration=True)
    f.write(xmlstr)

filenames = zip.namelist()
zip_copy_filename = 'output.docx'
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_copy_filename, "w") as docx:
    for filename in filenames:
        docx.write(os.path.join(tmp_dir,filename), filename)

shutil.rmtree(tmp_dir)
```